# Apache2 non-default root directory multiple websites 403 forbidden

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2, ubuntu-20.04

I have Ubuntu 20.04 servers on AWS in autoscaling group with EFS mounted at `/mnt/efs/fs1`

I use codedeploy for deployment of a non-default website. The bitbucket pipeline creates a zip file containing the website config and the website content. Codedeploy deployment part is as follows:

```
#extract content
unzip -o frontend-qa.zip
#copy site config
sudo mv /mnt/efs/fs1/sites-enabled/* /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
#update permissions
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /mnt/efs/fs1/www
sudo chmod 777 -R /mnt/efs/fs1/www
#reload apache
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

The `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` part responsible for directories and permissions

```
<Directory /mnt/efs/fs1/www>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The website vhost file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin admin@the_site
      ServerName the_site
      ServerAlias www.the_site
      DocumentRoot /mnt/efs/fs1/www/html/site_admin/public_html
      # Directory path where code exists
        <Directory /mnt/efs/fs1/www/html/site_admin/public_html>
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/the_site.site-error.log
        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel error
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/the_site.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The permissions on the site root

```
ll /mnt/efs/fs1/www/html/site_admin/public_html/
total 2120
drwxrwxrwx 10 www-data www-data    6144 Nov 28 16:35  ./
drwxrwxrwx  3 www-data www-data    6144 Nov 16 13:31  ../
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data     283 Nov 26 18:48  .gitignore*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data   13966 Nov 28 16:35  .htaccess*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data     305 Nov 26 18:48  .project*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data      23 Nov 26 18:48  HEAD*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data  343872 Nov 26 18:48 'Hi tea menu.pdf'*
drwxrwxrwx 15 www-data www-data    6144 Nov  5 23:39  application/
drwxrwxrwx 13 www-data www-data    6144 Nov  5 23:39  assets/
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data     339 Nov 26 18:48  composer.json*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data   65865 Nov 26 18:48  composer.lock*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data 1640731 Nov 26 18:48  composer.phar*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data      66 Nov 26 18:48  config*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data      73 Nov 26 18:48  description*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data      66 Nov 26 18:48  desktop.ini*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data       0 Nov 26 18:48  error.log*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data       0 Nov 26 18:48  git*
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data www-data    6144 Nov  5 23:39  hooks/
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data www-data   14336 Nov  5 23:39  images/
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data    6457 Nov 26 18:48  index.php*
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data www-data    6144 Nov  5 23:39  info/
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data    2496 Nov 26 18:48  license.txt*
drwxrwxrwx  8 www-data www-data    6144 Nov  5 23:40  system/
drwxrwxrwx  3 www-data www-data    6144 Nov  5 23:39  uploads/
drwxrwxrwx 22 www-data www-data    6144 Nov  5 23:46  vendor/
```

When I try to load the website, I get `403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.`

`/var/log/apache2/access.log` is empty

`/var/log/apache2/error.log` has the following:

```
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html
```

`/var/log/apache2/the_site.log` is empty

`/var/log/apache2/the_site-error.log` is empty as well

Would appreciate your help

Thanks
Igal

Comment: Are permissions on folder's set correctly? Maybe AppArmor, but not likely.

Comment: @dexter all the folders and files are 777 and owned by www-data:www:data

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by re-mounting the EFS volume under `/var/www`