# I get directory listing instead of the website index.php

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2, ubuntu-20.04

Ubuntu 20.04, Apache 2.4, PHP5.6

I have website with the following vhost config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin admin@website.com
      ServerName website.com
      ServerAlias www.website.com
      DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site_admin/public_html
      # Directory path where code exists
        <Directory /var/www/html/site_admin/public_html>
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/website.com-error.log
        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel error
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/website.com.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

`.htaccess` is disabled

`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` has the following Directory module

```
<Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This is the website directory:

```
ll /var/www/html/site_admin/public_html/
total 2120
drwxrwxrwx 10 www-data www-data    6144 Dec  6 15:01  ./
drwxrwxrwx  3 www-data www-data    6144 Dec  6 03:37  ../
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data     283 Dec  6 03:45  .gitignore*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data   14016 Dec  6 15:00  .htaccess.bck*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data     305 Dec  6 03:45  .project*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data      23 Dec  6 03:45  HEAD*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data  343872 Dec  6 03:45 'Hi tea menu.pdf'*
drwxrwxrwx 15 www-data www-data    6144 Dec  6 03:35  application/
drwxrwxrwx 13 www-data www-data    6144 Dec  6 03:35  assets/
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data     339 Dec  6 03:45  composer.json*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data   65865 Dec  6 03:45  composer.lock*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data 1640731 Dec  6 03:45  composer.phar*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data      66 Dec  6 03:45  config*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data      73 Dec  6 03:45  description*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data      66 Dec  6 03:45  desktop.ini*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data       0 Dec  6 03:45  error.log*
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data       0 Dec  6 03:45  git*
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data www-data    6144 Dec  6 03:35  hooks/
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data www-data   14336 Dec  6 03:35  images/
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data    6461 Dec  6 03:45  index.php*
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data www-data    6144 Dec  6 03:35  info/
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data www-data    2496 Dec  6 03:45  license.txt*
drwxrwxrwx  8 www-data www-data    6144 Dec  6 03:35  system/
drwxrwxrwx  3 www-data www-data    6144 Dec  6 03:35  uploads/
drwxrwxrwx 22 www-data www-data    6144 Dec  6 03:36  vendor/
```

When I try to browse the website at https://website.com, I get
[image: directory structure]

instead of the actual website

Please advise

Comment: That Virtualhost is for http. You are accessing the server via https. A different VirtualHost block matches that points to /var/www/html/

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I've added the same block for <VirtualHost *:443> but still get the same

Answer (score 0):

Is php installed?  What does php.info give you?  Also It seems all files have full 777 permission which a security risk.

Comment: yes, php is installed.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/qYYtNkk

Comment: And thank  you for reminding regarding the permissions - I updated it

Answer (score 0):

I figured the issue.
In my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, at the end, I had

```
# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional /mnt/efs/fs1/sites-enabled/*.conf
```

This was due to [Apache2 non-default root directory multiple websites 403 forbidden](https://serverfault.com/questions/1116819/apache2-non-default-root-directory-multiple-websites-403-forbidden) configuration

Once I changed this part to

```
# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

The site started working

Thanks